# How to insert into sqlite when button is pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, insert

I am trying to insert a string into a sqlite database with Objective-C (latest xcode), however for some strange reason every example I find on stackoverflow or on the internet in general somehow does not seem to work for me.

Im not using any sdk, so it's plain objective c.

Does anyone have a working piece of example code that actually works and inserts data into the database which can be retriveable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3 *database;    

if(sqlite3_open(___database file path__, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString  * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ VALUES %@",___table name___,___value___];
    const char * sqlStatement = [str UTF8String];
}
else 
{
    //ERROR
    return;
}

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        for (int i = 0;; i++)
        {
            char * ch;
            if ((ch = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i)))
            {
                NSString * ret = [NSString stringWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            }
            else 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

this code insert value in table like this..

Comment: very clean and understandable code. Thank you very much for your effort. I will test it and come back